# pytorch - PINN - Loss function not getting updated

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to work on a simple PINN, but for some reason the the loss function is not getting updated.

```
x = torch.linspace(-1,1,50).view(-1,1)
x.requires_grad = True
y = 2*x*x

class net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.tanh(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
    
model = net()

optimizer= torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(5001):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    pred = model(x)
    
    #loss = criterion(pred,y)
    dydx = torch.autograd.grad(pred,x,torch.ones_like(x),retain_graph=True)[0]
    
    loss = 0.01*torch.sum(dydx-4*x)
    
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer.step()
    
    if epoch%100 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch : {epoch}\tLoss: {loss.item()}')
        print(torch.sum(dydx-4*x).item())
```

I tried varying the coefficients of the loss function.

Comment: What do you mean with the loss not getting updated? What _exactly_ happens?

Comment: After each epoch, when I print out the loss it is the same as the initial one. The weights are not getting updated.

Comment: Can you check whether `optimizer.step()` changes the parameters?

Comment: The model parameters are not getting updated

Comment: Oh I think you need to calculate the gradient of the loss and not the gradient of the model.

Comment: Hmm, could you tell me what I should do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Currently, you seem to be calculating the loss using the gradient. Maybe you want to remove the `dydx = torch.autograd.grad(pred,x,torch.ones_like(x),retain_graph=True)[0]` and instead of `loss = 0.01*torch.sum(dydx-4*x)`, you'd use `loss = 0.01*torch.sum(pred-y)` or whatever (I don't know how you want to calculate the loss and you might also want to square it or similar)?

Comment: I am trying to do a unsupervised training of the NN, just by giving the differential equation as loss criteria. That is why, I calculated the differential dydx.

Comment: Does passing `create_graph=True` to `torch.autograd.grad` change anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. You want to create graph (not only retain graph), so `dydx` is actually treated not as a constant but as a function on network parameters. See explaination for example [here](https://github.com/mjmikulski/pinnacolada/blob/first-samples/cookbook/intro_to_gradients/part_1_leaf_that_require_grad.md#taking-derivatives-with-autogradgrad-function)

In simple words you should change

```py
dydx = torch.autograd.grad(pred,x,torch.ones_like(x),retain_graph=True)[0]
```

to

```py
dydx = torch.autograd.grad(pred, x, torch.ones_like(x), create_graph=True)[0]
```

2. The loss goes to minus infinity. I guess that you wanted to minimize the difference `dydx - 4 * x`. To do so take a square or abs value of that.

In simple words you should change

```py
loss = 0.01*torch.sum(dydx-4*x)
```

to

```py
loss = 0.01 * torch.sum((dydx - 4 * x) ** 2)
```

After doing 1 and 2, I get:

```
...
Epoch : 4800    Loss: 2.3030181637295755e-06
-0.00015908479690551758
Epoch : 4900    Loss: 2.1646274035447277e-06
-0.00014454126358032227
Epoch : 5000    Loss: 2.031747271757922e-06
-0.00015157461166381836
```

Hope it helps :)